# How to make GNU GRUB automatically boot Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, linux, windows-7, ubuntu-11.04, grub

How to make Windows Boot Manager automatically open GNU GRUB and then with GNU GRUB automatically boot Linux Ubuntu 11.04. Please answer detailed with the proceedings.
Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit GRUB's config file:

```
/boot/grub/grub.conf
```

There, you put your linux partition as default.

```
default=0
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS (2.6.8-1.523)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.8-1.523 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
    initrd /initrd-2.6.8-1.523.img

# section to load Windows 
title Windows
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1
```

`default` in this example is **0**, the first entry of your GRUB menu.

Comment: Are you sure, that's wright patrition?